# Can't get setcookie() to work right

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I wrote the following class, Cookie.php

```
class Cookie extends Config{

//Variables declaration
private $cookieName;
private $cookieValue;
private $cookieExpireTime;
private $cookiePath;
private $cookieDomain;
private $cookieSecureThroughSSL;
private $cookieOnlyThroughHTTP;

//Constructor method, creates a new cookie with the assigned values
function __construct($presetCookieName,
                     $presetCookieValue,
                     $presetCookieExpireTime,
                     $presetCookiePath='/',
                     $presetCookieDomain = NULL,
                     $presetCookieSecureThroughSSL = false,
                     $presetCookieOnlyThroughHTTP = true){

    $this->cookieName = $presetCookieName;
    $this->cookieValue = $presetCookieValue;
    $this->cookieExpireTime = $presetCookieExpireTime;
    $this->cookiePath = $presetCookiePath;
    $this->cookieDomain = $presetCookieDomain;
    $this->cookieSecureThroughSSL = $presetCookieSecureThroughSSL;
    $this->cookieOnlyThroughHTTP = $presetCookieOnlyThroughHTTP;

    return $this->createCookie();
}

//Clean cookie from possible malicious HTML code, or mistakenly typed spaces
private function cleanCookieValue($value){
    return htmlspecialchars(str_replace(' ', '', $value));
}

//Create a new cookie function
public function createCookie(){
    return setcookie($this->cleanCookieValue($this->cookieName),
                     $this->cleanCookieValue($this->cookieValue),
                     $this->cleanCookieValue($this->cookieExpireTime),
                     $this->cleanCookieValue($this->cookiePath),
                     $this->cleanCookieValue($this->cookieDomain),
                     $this->cleanCookieValue($this->cookieSecureThroughSSL),
                     $this->cleanCookieValue($this->cookieOnlyThroughHTTP));
}
```

And the following test file:

```
$cookie = new Cookie("testCookie", "Value", 3600, "/");

if(isset($_COOKIE['testCookie'])){
    echo 'Success';
}
else{
    echo 'Failed!';
}
```

And I keep getting 'Failed' error (After two or more refreshes as well).
Do you guys see the problem here?

By the way, the following simple example works perfectly:

```
setcookie("token", "value", time()+60*60*24*100, "/");

if(isset($_COOKIE['token'])){
    echo 'Token succeeded';
}
else{
    echo 'Token failed!';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the class, you had posted 3rd parameter is `$presetCookieExpireTime`, not "seconds of life". To make it work - do the

```
$cookie = new Cookie("testCookie", "Value", time() + 3600, "/");
```